# How can I move this text so there is some whitespace on the right side within the tr or td?

Tags: html, html-table

I need to move this over within the table row so there is some whitespace on the right of the text and padding doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <h1>Release of daptive Security 1.4.1</h1>
        <h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3></p></h4>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: To add some padding to your text inside the cell, just add `padding-left:10px` to the `tr`element. Also note that 1) you have a closing `<h3>` which was never opened, 2) `<p>` element inside `<h4>` *(and other `<h>` elements)* is not valid according to html5 spec

Comment: Show what you mean about padding doesn't seem to do anything. Show what you tried in a js/html snippet so we can run it.